# Android Recyclerview doesn't delete old views when recycling

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm having this issue where the old viewHolder of a position in the recyclerview isn't deleted or reset before recycling it. In my case this means that if I scroll and go back to the former position it now has two views stacked on top of each other. I tried solving this by setting the visiblity of the view to be inflated to gone but this is a solution for the short run and I want to understand how to really solve this. I also tried to setRecycble(false) but then my views take longer to inflate and recycling the views also makes more sense My Adapter code is below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.chatr.app.android.Interfaces.MessageListParent;
import com.chatr.app.android.Models.ChatrInvitePending;
import com.chatr.app.android.Models.ChatrMessagingInfo;
import com.chatr.app.android.R;
import com.chatr.app.android.Repositories.MessageRepository;
import com.chatr.app.android.RoomDB.ChatDatabase.ChatEntity;
import com.chatr.app.android.RoomDB.MessagesDatabase.MessageEntity;
import com.chatr.app.android.Tools.ChatrApplication;
import com.chatr.app.android.Tools.ChatrErrorHandler;
import com.chatr.app.android.Views.MessageItemView;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static com.chatr.app.android.Manager.MessageManager.CONSTANT_OTHER_TYPE;
import static com.chatr.app.android.Manager.MessageManager.CONSTANT_SELF_TYPE;

public class MessageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    //Constants
    private static final String TAG = "MessageListAdapter";
    private static final int CONSTANT_MESSAGE_TYPE = 0;
    private static final int CONSTANT_INFORMATION_TYPE = 1;
    //Data list
    private final ArrayList<MessageEntity> messageEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<Object> additionalInformationList = new ArrayList<>();


    //Callback
    private final MessageListParent parentCallback;

    public MessageListAdapter(MessageListParent parent) {
        this.parentCallback = parent;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (viewType == CONSTANT_MESSAGE_TYPE) {
            MessageItemView messageItemView = new MessageItemView(parent.getContext());
            messageItemView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            viewHolder = new MessageViewHolder(messageItemView);
        }
        else if(viewType == CONSTANT_INFORMATION_TYPE){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_view_information_text,parent);
            //v.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            viewHolder = new InformationTextViewHolder(v);
        }
        return viewHolder;


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Object v = null;
        for(Object obj : additionalInformationList){
            if (additionalInformationList.get(position) instanceof ChatrInvitePending){
                if (((ChatrInvitePending)
                        additionalInformationList.get(position)).getRecyclerViewPosition() == position){
                    v = obj;
                    break;

                }

            }
            else if (additionalInformationList.get(position) instanceof ChatrMessagingInfo){
                if (((ChatrMessagingInfo)
                        additionalInformationList.get(position)).getRecyclerViewPosition() == position){
                    v = obj;
                    break;

                }


            }
        }
        if (v == null){
            return CONSTANT_MESSAGE_TYPE;
        }
        else{
            return CONSTANT_INFORMATION_TYPE;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
            case CONSTANT_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                generateMessageTypeView((MessageViewHolder) holder, position);
            case CONSTANT_INFORMATION_TYPE:
                //generateInformationTypeView((InformationTextViewHolder) holder, position);


        }


    }

   
    public void generateMessageTypeView(MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try{
            holder.messageItemView.setFormerEntity(messageEntityList.get(position-1));
        }catch (Exception e){
            ChatrErrorHandler.handleException(e);
        }
        holder.messageItemView.setEntity(messageEntityList.get(position));

        if(!messageEntityList.get(position).isRead()) {
            parentCallback.viewIsRead(messageEntityList.get(position));
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageEntityList.size();
    }

    public void updateMessageList(List<MessageEntity> messageEntitiesList) {
        this.messageEntityList.clear();
        this.messageEntityList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(messageEntitiesList));
        notifyItemInserted(messageEntitiesList.size());

    }
    public void updateAdditionalInfoList(List<Object> additionalList) {
        this.additionalInformationList.clear();
        this.additionalInformationList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(additionalList));
        notifyItemInserted(additionalList.size());

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull @NotNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder = (MessageViewHolder) holder;
        messageViewHolder.messageItemView.clear();
    }

    public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final MessageItemView messageItemView;
        public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            messageItemView = (MessageItemView) itemView;
        }
    }
    public static class InformationTextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final TextView textView;
        public InformationTextViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_information_text_chat);
        }
    }

}
```

Here you can see the issue I have:

[image: Screenshot of the Recyclerview after sco]

Here is my view that I inflate:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.chatr.app.android.Manager.MediaManager;
import com.chatr.app.android.Manager.MessageManager;
import com.chatr.app.android.R;
import com.chatr.app.android.Repositories.ChatRepository;
import com.chatr.app.android.Repositories.MessageRepository;
import com.chatr.app.android.RoomDB.ChatDatabase.ChatEntity;
import com.chatr.app.android.RoomDB.MediaDatabase.MediaEntity;
import com.chatr.app.android.RoomDB.MessagesDatabase.MessageEntity;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MessageItemView extends FrameLayout {
    private static final long CONSTANT_TIME_5_MIN = 300000;
    private int viewType = 1;
    private MessageEntity messageEntity;
    private TextView txtContent;
    private TextView txtTime;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private AudioMessageView audioMessageView;
    private ChatrGradientView chatrGradientView;

    private final String regexEmoji = "([\\u20a0-\\u32ff\\ud83c\\udc00-\\ud83d\\udeff\\udbb9\\udce5-\\udbb9\\udcee])";

    private static final String TAG = "MessageItemView";
    private MessageEntity formerMessageEntity;

    public MessageItemView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public MessageItemView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public MessageItemView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    }

    public MessageItemView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    }

    private void init() {
        Log.d(TAG, "init: " + viewType);
        if (viewType == MessageManager.CONSTANT_OTHER_TYPE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "init:3 ");
            LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_other_message_view_item, this);
        }
        if (viewType == MessageManager.CONSTANT_SELF_TYPE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ini2t: " + viewType);
            LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_self_message_view_item, this);


        }
        initViews();
    }
    @NotNull
    public String convertMillisToTime(long millis) {
        Log.d(TAG, "convertMillisToTime: " + millis);
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.GERMANY);
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2" +
                ""));
        return formatter.format(new Date(millis*1000));
    }


    private void initViews() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initViews: ");
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.img_content_message_item);
        txtContent = findViewById(R.id.txt_content_message_item);
        txtTime = findViewById(R.id.message_date_indicator_txt);
        chatrGradientView = findViewById(R.id.img_message_item_profile_pic);
        audioMessageView = findViewById(R.id.audio_message_view_in_message);

        ChatRepository.get(getContext())
                .getStartGradientChatEntity(messageEntity.getChatId(), new ChatRepository.GetGradient() {
                    @Override
                    public void getGradient(int color) {
                        chatrGradientView.setGradientStartColor(color);
                    }
                });
        ChatRepository.get(getContext())
                .getEndGradientChatEntity(messageEntity.getChatId(), new ChatRepository.GetGradient() {
                    @Override
                    public void getGradient(int color) {
                        chatrGradientView.setGradientEndColor(color);
                    }
                });

        imageView.setVisibility(GONE);
        txtContent.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        if (formerMessageEntity == null || formerMessageEntity.getDateSent() > CONSTANT_TIME_5_MIN ){
            txtTime.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            txtTime.setText(convertMillisToTime(messageEntity.getDateSent()));
        }
        if (messageEntity != null) {
            imageView.setVisibility(GONE);
            txtContent.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            txtContent.setText(messageEntity.getContentText());

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "run-3: ");
        if (messageEntity.getMediaId()!= -1){
            txtContent.setVisibility(GONE);

            Log.d(TAG, "run-2: " + messageEntity.getMediaId());
            MessageRepository.get(getContext()).getMediaWithId(messageEntity.getMediaId(),
                    new MessageRepository.getMediaEntity() {
                @Override
                public void getMedia(MediaEntity mediaEntity) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "run-1: " + mediaEntity);

                    mediaAvailabilityWork(mediaEntity);

                }
            });


        }
        else{
            Glide.with(MessageItemView.this).clear(imageView);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
            imageView.setVisibility(GONE);

        }
        Matcher matchEmo = Pattern.compile(regexEmoji).matcher(txtContent.getText());
        while(matchEmo.find()){
            Log.d(TAG, "initViews: ");
            Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(txtContent.getText());

            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), matchEmo.start(),
                    matchEmo.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            txtContent.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        }
    }

    public void mediaAvailabilityWork(MediaEntity mediaEntity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "run0: ");
        if (mediaEntity != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "run1: " +mediaEntity.getTypeMedia());
            if (mediaEntity.getTypeMedia().equals(MediaManager.CONSTANT_MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)){
                audioMessageView.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "run2: ");
                        audioMessageView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                        imageView.setVisibility(GONE);
                        audioMessageView.setMediaEntity(mediaEntity);

                    }
                });
            }
            else if (mediaEntity.getTypeMedia().equals(MediaManager.CONSTANT_MEDIA_TYPE_IMG)){
                imageView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "run3123123: ");
                        imageView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                        audioMessageView.setVisibility(GONE);

                        Glide.with(MessageItemView.this).
                                load(mediaEntity.getFileUrl()).centerCrop().into(imageView);



                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }


    public void setEntity(MessageEntity messageEntity) {
        this.viewType = messageEntity.getChatType();
        this.messageEntity = messageEntity;
        Log.d(TAG, "setEntity: " + messageEntity.getMediaId());
        init();
    }


    public void setFormerEntity(MessageEntity formerMessageEntity) {
        this.formerMessageEntity = formerMessageEntity;
    }

    public void clear() {
        viewType = 1;
        txtTime.setText("");
        txtContent.setText("");
        audioMessageView.setVisibility(GONE);
        txtContent.setVisibility(GONE);
        this.postInvalidate();

    }

}
```

Comment: View holders don't get automatically reset by the system. It is up to you to reset whatever fields need to be reset and this is generally done in `onBindViewHolder()`. In other words, if there are fields in a view holder that should be changed from one use to another, that is up to the developer.

Comment: Yes of course, however I do set the views. For instance, I set the dateTxtView to "5min ago" but the problem is that the former view is below the new one and although my view now states "5min ago" beneath it is the old view which has totally different infos which I can't access. Just like when you add a Fragment and don't replace the old one and now one can see two fragments stacked on each other.

Comment: Truly odd. The only other possible issue that I see is that you are falling through your switch statement in `onBindViewHolder()` but you may mean to or you are posting partial code and the actual code behaves.

Comment: @Cheticamp I added my code for the view that I inflate. Perhaps my mistake lies there. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, the custom view changes the complexion of this problem a little. You inflate the layouts into the custom view as the parent. You would see the overlay if you inflate more than once into the same custom view. This is definitely something to look into.

Comment: Just saw your message: Having a look at it right now....If I call removeAllViews inside of the init() method only the pieces that I need get rendered. So this is a temporary solution. However, now the views have to reload everytime I scroll and thus has the same effect as: setRecyclable(false)

Comment: So, you are inflating more than once inside the same instantiation of the custom view. I suggest that you not do that and inflate only once and, once inflated, that instantiation of the custom view will either be an "other" message or "self" message. I wouldn't try to change the characteristic of the custom view once instantiated.

Comment: Commented that line of code (only one inflate remains). Didn't change anything :(

Comment: OK, but are you calling that inflate more than once for the same instantiation of the custom view?

Comment: Whenever `onBindViewHolder()` is called, it calls `generateMessageTypeView()` for `CONSTANT_MESSAGE_TYPE`. `generateMessageTypeView()` calls `setEntity()` which calls `init()` which inflates the view. Inflate is being called over and over when views are bound. This is the problem. I suggest inflating the view in the custom view's constructors. That way you will only inflate once.

Comment: oh. Understood. Will try that out later. Sounds promising

Comment: So I added some code according to your logic, looked at another stack post and finally solved the problem. Have a great day Cheticamp :) PS: You were correct